# Revolution R says I need to update to VS2008 SP1 but I have VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, revolution-r

While installing `Revolution R`, it tries to install `Visual Studio 2008 Isolated Shell SP1`, but fails because it says that I have a previous version of VS installed that needs to be updated first.

The problem is that I have `VS2010 SP1` already installed.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I solved the problem by tweaking the register.
I post it in case somebody needs it:

You need to check these registry keys:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VC\Servicing\9.0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VC\Servicing\9.0\RED\1033
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\9.0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\9.0\VSR\1033

and ensure that the SP and SPIndex values are 1 and that the SPName is SP1.
The SP and SPIndex values were 0 and the SPName was RTM.
And repeat the process for VS 8.0  keys

Maybe this could cause problems with future upgrades.